# Securing a Nintendo Homepass Network

Tags: linux, dns, firewall, wireless-access-point

Some Nintendo 3DS users have been setting up wireless access points to trick their handheld console into treating the AP as an official "Nintendo Zone" AP. This has become known as a "Homepass" setup. The typical Linux Homepass AP setup involves running `hostapd` on a wireless NIC with SSID "NZ@McD1" and a spoofed MAC address. The wireless network is then NAT'd to a second NIC connected to their home network, allowing outgoing network traffic. In the past, users have been able to encrypt this AP with a password to prevent unauthorized access. A recent 3DS OS update changed the requirements such that the AP must have no encryption. Because of this, Homepass users must find other ways to restrict the AP.

A packet capture of a 3DS Homepass exchange shows DNS queries for the following:

```
conntest.nintendowifi.net
nppl.c.app.nintendowifi.net
npdl.cdn.nintendowifi.net
```

Based on the fact that there's only a few domains that need to be accessed, and since it's the same domains every time, here's how I'm thinking the AP should be restricted:

- Setup a caching DNS on the AP, which only resolves queries under the `nintendowifi.net` domain. This should prevent any IP-over-DNS.
- Any incoming packet on the AP interface should either be destined for the aforementioned caching DNS, or going out to one of the domains listed above. Everything else should be dropped.

Is this kind of setup even possible? If so, what would be the best way to do it? Also, is there anything missing here in terms of access restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Nintendo Wireless (If someone wants to purchase me some Nintendo gear to test it, I don't mind gaining experience!).

However, if you are trying to restrict wireless connections over hostapd, I do have experience with that:

Edit your hostapd file and add the following lines:

> macaddr_acl=1
>
> accept_mac_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd-mac.accept

If you already have the top line set to 0, change it to 1.

Next, create the file `/etc/hostapd/hostapd-mac.accept`, and place your device's MAC address there.

MAC Addresses can be spoofed, but this should stop the average person connecting in.

For additional security and your actual question, you really need to know exactly what hosts your Nintendo device connects to and restrict it as any sort of open internet is open to abuse - even if you block DNS, I can always connect to a VPN via IP only and then tunnel out...

Comment: Good answer, I had forgotten about MAC address filtering. It offers good protection against the vast majority of internet users. I want to keep out as many people as possible of course, but this provides good value in terms of time spent configuring vs. number of people kept out.

Answer (score 0):

Nintendo zones can be unencrypted or encrypted. The situation for firmwares 9.2 and prior was that, the 3DS will connect to nzone ssids that were designated to be unencrypted even when encryption is in place, and these ssids happen to include attwifi/NZ@McD1 etc. In the later firmwares, these access points are no longer regarded as valid nzones.

The ssids designated to use encryption, do so with preset passwords stored in the 3DS itself, so any attempt to spoof them must be done with the same passwords.